# PHP Sort array joint positions

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of players each with a number of points.

I can easily sort the array in order of the points using a custom usort function.

But when two players have the same amount of points I need to rank them as the same winning position within the list.

E.g.

- Nick - 25
- Tom - 18
- Chris - 18
- Dave - 16
- James - 8

In this case the data that I require would be

- Nick - 1st
- Tom - (joint) 2nd
- Chris - (joint) 2nd
- Dave 3rd
- James 4th

So players with equal scores are designated the same ranking position.

What is the best way of calculating these positions?

Thanks!

Comment: you can solve this as key value using associative array like `['1' => ['someone'], '2' => ['oneguy','another guy'] ]`

Comment: What have you tried? How does your current code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you what you want with an additional fix: if you have two players in position 2 the next player should be in position 4. If you don't want this additional fix move `$count++;` into the if statement.

```
$count = 0;
$position = 0;
$last_score = -1;

foreach ($players as $player)
{
    $count++;

    if ($last_score !== $player->score)
    {
        $position = $count;
    }

    $player->position = $position;
    $last_score = $player->score;
}
```

Comment: Perfect and the simplest solution by far. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

I think the following code would do the job as required:

```
$scores = array('Nick'=>25,'Tom'=>18,'Chris'=>18,'Dave'=>16, 'James'=> 8,);

$scores_numbers = array_unique(array_values($scores)); 
$scores_counter = array_count_values($scores);
$pos = 1;
foreach($scores_numbers as $num) {
    foreach($scores as $name=>$score) {
      if($num == $score) {
        if($scores_counter[$score] > 1) {
          echo  "$name - (joint) $pos<br />";
        } else {
          echo  "$name - $pos<br />";
        }
      }
    }
  $pos++;
}
```

I have updated the code to avoid the duplicating output.

Answer (score 1):

If you are retrieving player stats from DB then below code can be useful to rank them :

```
<?php

$players = [
    ['name' => 'Ash',
    'point' => 0
    ],
    ['name' => 'Bob',
     'point' => 10
    ],
    ['name' => 'Cane',
    'point' => 0
    ],
    ['name' => 'Dory',
    'point' => 6
    ],
    ['name' => 'Efat',
    'point' => 6
    ],
  ];

usort($players, function($v1, $v2){
    return $v2['point'] - $v1['point'];
});

$ranking = [];

$currentPosition = 0;
$heighestPoint = PHP_INT_MIN;

foreach($players as $player){
    if($heighestPoint !== $player['point']){
        $currentPosition++;
        $heighestPoint = $player['point'];
    }

        $ranking[$currentPosition][] = $player;
}

print_r($ranking);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Bob
                [point] => 10
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Dory
                [point] => 6
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Efat
                [point] => 6
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Ash
                [point] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Cane
                [point] => 0
            )

    )

 )
```

Answer (score 1):

May it helps

```
/*Below array must be sorted  */
$a1=array("Nick"=>25,"Tom"=>18,"Chris"=>18,"Dave"=>16,"James"=>8); 

$makeUnique=array_unique($a1);
$makeUnique=array_values($makeUnique);

$pArr=array_map('setPosition',$a1);

print_r($pArr);


function setPosition($a){
    Global $makeUnique;
    return array_search($a,$makeUnique)+1;
}
```

OUT PUT

Array ( [Nick] => 1 [Tom] => 2 [Chris] => 2 [Dave] => 3 [James] => 4 )

Answer (score 0):

I used [`usort`](http://php.net/usort) to sort assoc array

```
$players = [["name" => "Nick" , "score" => 25] , ["name" => "Tom" , "score" => 18] , ["name" => "chris" , "score" => 18] , ["name" => "dave" , "score" => 16 ] , ["name" => "james" , "score" => 8]];

usort($players , function($a , $b) {return $b["score"] - $a["score"];} );

var_dump($players);

$lastScore = null;
$pos = 1;
foreach($players as $player)
{
    if($lastScore != null && $lastScore == $player["score"])
        echo $pos-1 . " - " . $player["name"] . '<br/>';
    else
        echo $pos++ . " - " . $player["name"] . '<br/>';

    $lastScore = $player["score"];
}
```

checkout this code in [**teh playground**](https://www.tehplayground.com/ZxDRiy7Vc4ijOCnZ)